# Insert operation has no effect in sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

In my android app, im trying to populate a row with notes and title if the book number is 0, chapter number is 1 and verse count is 1. This is my query

```
INSERT or replace INTO tbl_name ("Notes","Title")
SELECT notes, title FROM tbl_name WHERE  book = 0 and chapter = 1 and versecount = 1;
```

But this query does not perform the insert operation. why so?

Comment: Check your logcat.  SQL errors cause exceptions, which are frequently written into the log and ignored.

Comment: You are replacing some rows with rows that you read from the same table; this does not make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget `VALUES`  part in `INSERT or REPLACE` Query. do it as :

```
INSERT or REPLACE INTO tbl_name ("Notes","Title") 
                          VALUES("Notes text","Title text");
```

Comment: The VALUES clause [*can* be replaced with a query](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html).